# How do I find all the Sunday-dates between 2 dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with `time-created` and `time closed`.

Both columns are `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` objects.

Like this:

```
time-created | time-closed 
 2018-01-01    2018-01-10
 2018-03-10    2018-04-15
     .             .
     .             .
```

I want to be able to generate a list on a separate column that shows **ALL** the dates that land on a **Sunday** in between the 2 dates for every row in the dataframe.

Something like this:

```
time-created | time-closed | Sunday_dates
 2018-01-01    2018-01-10    [2018-01-06]
 2018-03-10    2018-04-15    [2018-03-11, 2018-03-18, 2018-03-25]
     .             .
     .             .
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nice. Have you done any research? If so, could you please share it with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def sundays(row):
    s = pd.date_range(row['time-created'], row['time-closed'])
    return s[s.weekday == 6].to_list()

df['Sundays'] = df.apply(sundays, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
  time-created time-closed                                                                                                                         Sundays
0   2018-01-01  2018-01-10                                                                                                           [2018-01-07 00:00:00]
1   2018-03-10  2018-04-15  [2018-03-11 00:00:00, 2018-03-18 00:00:00, 2018-03-25 00:00:00, 2018-04-01 00:00:00, 2018-04-08 00:00:00, 2018-04-15 00:00:00]
```

Comment: I got 'KeyError: ('time-created', 'occurred at index 0')'

Comment: What does `df.columns` return?

Comment: Oh wait sorry my column was just misnamed haha.